# Weighted Averages in PowerView

Tags: excel, powerview

My objective is to create a weighted average of price where the weights depend on the value of size per category, using the PowerView functionality in Excel 2013. For instance the following table:

Table

```
Category  Price    Size
1         10        5
1         20       15
2         30        3
2         50        8
3          5       10
3         33       10
```

So, for category 1: (10*5+20*15)/20=17.5 and present this in a table:

```
Category   weighted avg price
 1         17.5
 2        ....
```

Instead of the unweighted averages which the standard functionality of PowerView produces. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure about PowerView but with standard PivotTables you can create a custom calculation - the quick alternative is to create an additional column which has the weighted value and then run the average over it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be any new information for you, but you could create two new columns.  Column D that is just B x C.  And then a column E that is

```
=sumif($A$1:$A$6,A1,$D$1:$D$6)/sumif($A$1:$A$6,A1,$C$1:$C$6)
```

and that will give you the weighted average for each category.